# Creating groups in database query

Tags: r, grouping

```
  TRANSACTION_DATE_TIME TRANSACTION_AMOUNT TRANSACTION_TYPE TRANSACTION_MODE
1    2010-4-1.18.0. 17. 0               2000       Withdrawal             Cash
2   2010-4-2.14.44. 47. 0               2000       Withdrawal             Cash
3   2010-4-2.16.53. 33. 0               6000       Withdrawal             Cash
4   2010-4-5.16.22. 26. 0               2100       Withdrawal             Cash
5   2010-4-7.21.23. 11. 0                 99       Withdrawal             Cash
6   2010-4-8.16.15. 35. 0                700       Withdrawal             Cash
7  2010-4-15.18.11. 17. 0                250          Deposit         Transfer
8  2010-4-17.14.17. 58. 0                737          Deposit         Transfer
9  2010-4-19.14.19. 42. 0               1600       Withdrawal             Cash
10 2010-4-30.15.55. 49. 0              13950          Deposit         Transfer
```

This is my matrix obtained from DB Query. I want to group the rows based on `TRANSACTION_TYPE` and find the corresponding sum of `TRANSACTION_AMOUNT` for Withdrawal and Deposit group. Help me out to do the same in R language.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to attack this, but one way is to use the package `sqldf` which allows you to perform SQL-like operations on data frames.  One thing that I have learned along the way is that you can not have dots "." in names or `sqldf` will choke.

```
data_summary <- sqldf("SELECT TRANSACTION_TYPE, SUM(TRANSACTION_AMOUNT) as Total FROM df GROUP BY TRANSACTION_TYPE)
```

Comment: +1 Cool, I did not know you could do that. Its always driven me nuts that the convention in R is to use the . in variable names, when in most other major languages it is an operator for accessing members of a class. sqldf looks like one more reason to start using underscores or camel casing in variable names instead...

Comment: There are certainly other ways of doing this where you don't have to worry about the names.  Also, it might be worth looking into ?attach or ?with.  I rely on sqldf quite a bit, so I have gotten away from using a "." in a name.

Comment: sqldf supports several databases and the drivers of some of the supported databases do support names with dots.  e.g. with the H2 java database and the RH2 driver this works: `library(RH2); library(sqldf); sqldf ('select "Petal.Length" from iris limit 3')`

Comment: So I just installed sqldf and have been playing with it. It looks like it is mapping variable names with dots to underscores for me. For example, in the underlying csv file I have a column called Calendar Week. When loaded into a data frame, this becomes Calendar.Week. But, when I use sqldf to query this object I use Calendar_Week as the reference.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 additional options:

1. Add a grouping clause to the original database query, before you
   pull the data into R.
2. Check out the [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) package, e.g.:

   dtf <- data.frame(age=rchisq(100000,10),group=factor(sample(1:10,100000,rep=T)))
   dt <- data.table(dt)
   dt[,list(mean=mean(age),sd=sd(age)),by=group]

(Example [borrowed from here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/8230/2817))